# Equation for "square paraboloid".

Tags: geometry

Equation for paraboloid that looks something like this ...

[image]

... is simple. It's just $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$.

I don't know if there is better name than "square paraboloid". I didn't find any. But what I am looking for is and equation that will give me result like this:

[image]

*(Note that this is and illustration, not the precise result)*.

I need it for computation in a shader. I will normalize it so that points that are outside a certain square give results bigger than 1, points inside give results smaller than 1 and points inside squares' border go smoothly from 0 to 1.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x, y) = \left( \max ( |x|, |y| ) \right)^2 
$$

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do nicely.

Comment: Let's say I would like to round the corners. Is that a simple modification or would it be too complicated?

Comment: $$f(x, y) = (x^n + y^n)^{\frac{2}{n}}.$$ If you pick $n = 2$, you'll get your circular cone; if you pick $n = 10$, it'll look like rounded squares. For $n = 200$, it'll look almost like perfect squares. See if you can figure out why, as $n \to \infty$, this solution converges to the one I suggested above.

Comment: This looks really good although it requires a lot of nth power and finding roots which are pretty expensive operations. Squares will have to do then. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check on whether taking powers and $n$th roots of numbers between $0$ and $1$ really *is* slow in your shader language. You may be surprised. (Graphics cards were long ago optimized to compute the Phong reflectance model, which includes a high power of a cosine...)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the level curves of
$$f(x,y) = \max\{|x|,|y|\}.$$

Comment: To get the uneven spacing that OP wants, I think you need an exponent. Then again, maybe OP doesn't want uneven spacing...but the picture suggested that to me.